# Viewing/editing attributed relationship data in Identify/Attributes dialog in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes, relationship-class, identify

Is there any extension or standard  option to view/edit attributed relationship records attributes using standard ArcMap attribute editor and/or Identify windows?

Comment: I'm still not really sure what you're looking for -- relationship classes are just a way to tie in related tables.  They don't actually contain any attribute data.

Comment: @Roy: they can contain data--when you create the relationship class, you can choose to add additional fields to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are talking about the related records or the rows in the actual relationship class.

If it's the related records, the attribute editor provides some basic editing abilities:
[image]

And you can edit the field values of the related table:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm talking about the actual relationship class rows that contain addition attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but I'll give it a shot.  You can get to the related records with the *Related Tables* button in the attribute table (once you have a feature selected), which is editable.
[image: Related Records]

In the Identify box you can see related records by using the + option under your main layer, but I don't believe it's editable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Roy, but it is not my case, look at the comment above.